# Possible to modify Excel VBA References at runtime (after runtime loading of an Add-In)?

Tags: vba, excel

When dynamically loading an Excel 2010 Add-In, one must also alter the VBA references to include the newly added Add-In, after it has been loaded into the workbook.

This code works for programmatically loading the add-in:

```
Function LoadAddin(strFilePath As String) As Boolean
   ' Checks whether add-in is in collection, and
   ' then loads it. To call this procedure, pass
   ' in add-in's path and file name.

   Dim addXL            As Excel.AddIn
   Dim strAddInName     As String

   On Error Resume Next
   ' Call ParsePath function to return file name only.
   'strAddInName = ParsePath(strFilePath, FILE_ONLY)    'not available in VBA...so it seems to always physically load it below, which seems to work fine.
   ' Remove extension from file name to get add-in name.
   strAddInName = Left(strAddInName, Len(strAddInName) - 4)
   ' Attempt to return reference to add-in.
   Set addXL = Excel.AddIns(strAddInName)
   If err <> 0 Then
      err.Clear
      ' If add-in is not in collection, add it.
      Set addXL = Excel.AddIns.Add(strFilePath)
      If err <> 0 Then
         ' If error occurs, exit procedure.
         LoadAddin = False
         GoTo exit_function
      End If
   End If
   ' Load add-in.
   If Not addXL.Installed Then addXL.Installed = True
   LoadAddin = True

exit_function:
   Exit Function
End Function
```

So is there a way to now add this to the References so VBA code in the host spreadsheet that refers to VBA within this newly included Add-In will execute properly?

It appears that the route to go might be something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile ("C:\MyFiles\MyAddin.xlam")
```

...but this gives me the error:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
Run-time error '32813':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Comment: If the host project has early-bound references to procedures in the add-in then you may get compilation errors if there's no existing reference: these errors don't always wait until you actually call the code referencing the other project...

Comment: @Tim:  I'm hoping to get around this by calling the load first thing in Workbook_Open().  Although, if Calculation is Auto when the spreadsheet is open it may be trouble.  Perhaps can load in an error handler somewhere....

Comment: Do you have "Trust access to VBProject" checked under Options ? And you've added a reference to the VBE extensibility library?

Comment: By the way its simpler to just open the XLA/XLAM workbook rather than try to add it to the addins collection.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: No, have moved onto something else for the time being...still would like to resolve this once and for all though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the same code (but slightly modified) in the Workbook open event of the Add-In?

If I understand you correctly then I guess this is what you want?

```
Public ShouldIContinue As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '~~> This is required to avoid the endless loop
    If ShouldIContinue = True Then Exit Sub

    Dim addXL As AddIn
    Dim strAddInName As String
    Dim oTempBk As Workbook

    strFilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    strAddInName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    '~~> This will work for both .xla and .xlam
    strAddInName = Left(strAddInName, (InStrRev(strAddInName, ".", -1, _
    vbTextCompare) - 1))

    On Error Resume Next
    Set addXL = Excel.AddIns(strAddInName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not addXL Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    '~~> This is required to avoid the Run-time error '1004':
    '~~> "Unable to get the Add property of the AddIns class"
    '~~> OR
    '~~> "Add method of addins class failed"
    '~~> when there are no workbooks
    Set oTempBk = Workbooks.Add

    Set addXL = AddIns.Add(strFilePath, True)
    addXL.Installed = True

    oTempBk.Close

    ShouldIContinue = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This might very well be correct, when I get back to this issue I will come back here and mark as correct if it fixes the issue.  Thanks.